# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database after deleting local.xml?

Tags: magento-1.9, local.xml

I'm using Magento 1.9 need to reconfigure. So I deleted local.xml file but then it shows following error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'site_db'

Why this happens?

Comment: clear the cache also

Comment: @Marius cleared but same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error say it's seems that you have not created the database `site_db` make sure all db details are correct in `app/etc/local.xml`.If all the info correct then you need to delete **var/cache** folder.

Comment: I deleted both local.xml file and cache folder but still appear above error.

Comment: @isuru do you want to reinstall ?

Comment: Yes I want to reinstall

Comment: delete all folder's under var/ folder. is "site_db" your old db ?